# o.s.w.c.request.async.WebAsyncManager : Could not complete async processing due to timeout or network error

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am getting the below timeout error while calling the java springboot API service. Code attached

*o.s.w.c.request.async.WebAsyncManager    : Could not complete async processing due to timeout or network error*

Also, I want to include concurrency in the service. Please let me know how to do.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
        configurer.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("stream-task");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this,

```
configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
```

You are actually wrongly configuring the timeout. The value passed in this method is the the amount of time, in milliseconds, before asynchronous request times out.

You should set it according to your use-case like set it to 5000 for 5 seconds. Or you can ignore this and **Spring** wil automatically set it to 10 seconds by default.

Comment: Hi Swayam. Thanks for the reply. I think setDefaultTimeout(-1) means infinite.